# DataTables != search

Tags: datatables

```js
var table = $('.dataTables-huntQueue').DataTable();
if($('#switch-mine').is(':checked')) {
    table.search( 'closed' ).draw();
} else {
    table.search( '' ).draw();
}
```

The above works great when all I'm looking for is the 'closed' value.  But what I really want is anything that is NOT closed.  Is there a ! operator here that I'm missing?

Comment: can you please elaborate your question bit more. Is your table server-side or client-side? what are you actually trying to do?

Comment: client side.  rendered in the browser.  I have a 6 column table shown to the client in the browser.  A user will want to see the list of all items that are NOT closed.  Currently... what I can show is the list that IS closed.  Less useful for the user!

Comment: what do you actually mean by close, is closing and opening dynamic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regular expression :

```js
table.search('^((?!(closed)).)*$', true, false, true).draw();
```

The meaning of the params is - see the documentation for [**`search()`**](https://datatables.net/reference/api/search()) :

- rows which **not** have columns containing "closed"
- It is a regular expression
- no "smart" filtering, in this case it doesnt seem to matter though
- case insensitive

---

The downside by using a regex through the API is that you will get an ugly  meaningless `^((?!(closed)).)*$` value in the search / filter box. Instead you can make a [**custom filter**](https://datatables.net/examples/plug-ins/range_filtering.html) that does exactly the same :

```js
function notSearch(notString) {
    notString = notString.toLowerCase();
    $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
       function(settings, data, dataIndex) {
           for (var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
              if (data[i].toLowerCase().indexOf(notString)>-1) return false;
           }
           return true;
       }  
    )
    table.draw();
    $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.pop();
}
```

Then call it by

```js
notSearch('closed');
```

---

You can even [**`register`**](https://datatables.net/manual/plug-ins/api) the above custom filter so it appears as part of the native API :

```js
jQuery.fn.dataTable.Api.register('notSearch()', function(notString) {
    notString = notString.toLowerCase();
    $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
       function(settings, data, dataIndex) {
           for (var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
              if (data[i].toLowerCase().indexOf(notString)>-1) return false;
           }
           return true;
       }  
    )
    table.draw();
    $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.pop();
})

table.rows().notSearch('closed');
```